# How to set application name and installation path while installing by AdminApp?

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

Just tried this thing for a day or two, able to do the installation using AdminApp command, but still got some problem about application name and installation path.

Reference I look from IBM said AppName is defined by display name, I think that mean it use the display name field from web.xml? But the result that I see is the application name will look like "Test_AP.war16dfd74ab1a", not exactly the same.

The installation path parameter part is also ambiguous, I don't think I see a thing looks like it.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html?view=embed#rxml_taskoptions__cmd10

```
import time

AdminApp.install('C:/Users/Development/Desktop/Test_AP.war', '-cell WIN-9DAB2SINode01Cell')

AdminConfig.save()

result = AdminApp.isAppReady('Test_AP')
while (result == "false"):
   ### Wait 5 seconds before checking again
   time.sleep(5)
   result = AdminApp.isAppReady('Test_AP')
print("Starting application...")
```

What I try to achieve is to use this script to install my service onto WAS with exact application name(same as my WAR name or display name in web.xml) and designated installation path, then start the service. But now I'm stuck at `com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7280E: An application with name "Test_AP_WAR" does not exist`. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: An easier way to create an `AdminApp.install` command would be to use the Admin Console. Go through like you normally would to install an enterprise application.  On the last page you will see a `help` box in the upper right corner.  Click on `view administrative scripting` and you will be provided with an `AdminApp.install` command.

Comment: From there you can edit the location your app is installed, and `-appname` option. I believe in your case you are not providing an `-appname` argument so WAS is generating one for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Simple Solution

You need to include an `-appname` argument such as:

```
AdminApp.install('C:/Users/Development/Desktop/Test_AP.war', ['-cell WIN-9DAB2SINode01Cell' -appname SimpleTestConnection5_war])
```

Otherwise WAS will generate an application name for you.

## Ideal Solution

Create an `AdminApp.install` command using the Admin Console. Install an enterprise application using the WAS Admin Console. On the last page, you will see a help box in the upper right corner. Click on `view administrative scripting` and you will be provided with an `AdminApp.install` command.  This command can be edited with a custom location and appname.

Comment: WOW! I never thought there is a such good thing at right side of admin console! thought it is just some helping messages xD. This is really helpful, brother!